# Rule_nos in dynamic ingress in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a dynamic nested block to create a list of ingress rules in a Network ACL:

```tf
resource "aws_network_acl" "network_acl" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.ssh_cidr_blocks
    iterator = cidr
    content {
      rule_no    = 100
      protocol   = "tcp"
      action     = "allow"
      cidr_block = cidr.value
      from_port  = 22
      to_port    = 22
    }
  }
}
```

As can be seen, I am generating an ingress for each CIDR in `var.ssh_cidr_blocks`.

This does not work however, and AWS sends back a message that the rule_no needs to be unique:

```
Error: Error creating ingress entry: NetworkAclEntryAlreadyExists: The network acl entry identified by 100 already exists.
        status code: 400, request id: c9b4b5ad-c1a9-4a85-a4e0-b0559e14ea53
```

I am a bit confused because Network ACLs in dynamic ingress rules are a class use-case for the dynamic nested blocks. Yet this doesn't even seem possible!

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `rule_no` is used for ordering (sort of a priority) for the rules, and they must be unique. If you don't care about the ordering, I suppose you could create a map variable and include a "fake" index. Though, I wonder if it's better to use `for_each` in the main resource block (that is, create many `network_acl` resources, each with a single ingress rule with `rule_no = 100`; not using `dynamic`) (I'm not sure that would work either though - can `rule_no` conflict over different acl's?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using range to avoid the duplicates on `rule_no`:

```
locals {
  ssh_cidr_blocks = [
    "10.0.208.0/20",
    "10.0.192.0/20",
    "10.0.224.0/20"
  ]
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "network_acl" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = range(length(local.ssh_cidr_blocks))
    iterator = i
    content {
      rule_no    = i.value
      protocol   = "tcp"
      action     = "allow"
      cidr_block = local.ssh_cidr_blocks[i.value]
      from_port  = 22
      to_port    = 22
    }
  }
}
```

Since all the acl rules are `allow` the order does not matter much and we can get away with that ...

---

But as you create more complex rules I'm not sure this will be acceptable since you will be mixing allow and deny and the order is important. You could follow @Kyle comment and use a map instead, in that case, the key is the `rule_no`, and the code will be something like:

```
locals {
  ssh_cidr_blocks = {
    100 = "10.0.208.0/20",
    200 = "10.0.192.0/20",
    500 = "10.0.224.0/20"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "network_acl" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = local.ssh_cidr_blocks
    content {
      rule_no    = ingress.key
      protocol   = "tcp"
      action     = "allow"
      cidr_block = ingress.value
      from_port  = 22
      to_port    = 22
    }
  }
}
```